# Aws Lex Network of bots

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-cloudformation, amazon-lex

I am trying to deploy AWS Lex Network of bots( currently 3 bots) in cloud formation, but it is throwing error while creating a stack. Does anyone have a solution, template format for deploying network to bots of aws lex in CF?

previously I have deployed single lex bot in CF. However with network of bots, I am facing issue.